# Mi ejecutable no abre

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

Estoy usando Pyinstaller para generar un ejecutable de mi programa.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Uso el siguiente comando en el terminal de Jupyter:

*pyinstaller --windowed --onefile --icon=./BASCULAICO.ico Dinamometro2.0.ipynb*

Todo bien hasta ahi, me crea el .exe y todo como se ve en la siguiente imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero cuando le doy click para finalmente poder abrirlo solo se pone la ruedita de cargando encima del cursor por un segundo y no pasa nada, como si no tuviese nada adentro. No salta ningún error, solo no reacciona

He intentado abrirlo desde el terminal pero me arroja el siguiente error. Ya me  he asegurado de escribirlo correctamente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Probaste abrir el .exe por el simbolo del sistema y ver si te muestra un error allí?

Comment: Puede ser el icono, me ha sucedido, intenta crearlo sin el.

Comment: te dejo el error que me sale en cmd en la pregunta editada

Comment: No lo es, ya he quitado el icono  y aun no reacciona